# Pronunciation of "banal" in British English?

Tags: british-english, pronunciation

How is "banal" properly pronounced in British English?

I know three ways to pronunciate banal but I don't know how to write them here.

Comment: The Oxford English Dictionary (2nd edition) has "/bəˈnɑːl/, older /ˈbeɪnəl/."

Comment: @Cerberus: I don't think I've ever heard that "older" version, so it would surprise me if that were one of the three ways OP claims to know (until now, I only knew *one*).

Comment: How do you define "proper pronunciation"?

Answer (score 4):

I'm a Brit and I say *b'narl*. Not rhyming with *canal* (short 'a's), nor *banorl* (all), and definitely never rhyming with *anal*.

Unfortunately I've no sound on my machine at the moment so I can't listen to Ledda's links.

How does [this site](http://www.howjsay.com/index.php?word=banal&submit=Submit) pronounce it?

Comment: It says /bə'nɑl/, American /bəˈnæl/. The first is how you said you say it, the second rhymes with canal. 

By the way, I made a mistake. The second rhymes with darl, how you say it.

Comment: In general Hiberno-English pronunciation, we'd say it to rhyme with canal, but with even stress on both syllables, rather than stres on the second (like in the linked version). Know OP is asking about British English, but just said I'd mention it for contrast purposes (& to point out that rhyming with canal could be with with even stress)

Answer (score 1):

After looking in a lot of dictionaries, there definitely seems to be a lot of disagreement in the pronunciation, or at least a lot of variation.

/bəˈnæl, -ˈnɑl, ˈbeɪnl/ seem to be the three I keep seeing.

That is, the first will rhyme with *canal*, the second with *darl*, and the last with *anal*.

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/banal

http://www.thefreedictionary.com/banal

http://dict.leo.org/#/search=banal&searchLoc=0&resultOrder=basic&multiwordShowSingle=on

I think the most interesting here is the pronunciation on Leo, which is clearly said by a native Brit. It's also the closest to the German pronunciation, although I believe the etymology is French, in which case it is pronounced almost the same.

Answer (score 1):

This link has sound recordings of both American and English pronunciations of *banal* http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/banal?q=banal#

Answer (score -1):

I went to a British colonial school and learned the one that rhymes with anal.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U Testy. In which country was that colonial school? I'm British and I've never heard it pronounced that way unless someone was mispronouncing it deliberately to be comically rude. I've always known it as 'banahl' with emphasis on the second syllable with a long 'a'.